# Can't serve javascript file with html - node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a webpage with an HTML, CSS, and JS file. It also has one image. I am able to get all of them to function and serve onto the client side, except for the javascript portion. It is most likely a silly syntax thing but I have not been able to solve it. 
Here is the code for my .js serving:

```
  else if(req.url === '/index.js'){
    console.log("SERVING JS")
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    var javaContents = fs.readFileSync('./public/index.js', {encoding: 'UTF8'});
    res.write(javaContents);
    res.end();
  }
```

^^^ Which is inside my requestHandler function:

```
function requestHandler(req, res){

}
```

Before this, I also have:

```
var http = require('http'), fs = require('fs');
var fs = require('fs');
```

And I declare my server variable last:

```
var server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(9934, function(){
    console.log("== Server is listening on port 9934");
});
```

I could post all my code but I think that is not necessary. Thank you!

Comment: You have `res.end()` which will just end the response, do you mean `res.send()`?

Comment: `can't server` is it returns 404? Is it return 200 with empty content?

Comment: maybe the javascript path is not right and 404 is because of that or maybe the content type should not be application/json it should be 'text/javascript'